# How to efficiently combine all subarrays with related id's and remove all duplicate objects

Tags: node.js, algorithm, sorting, lodash

[image]
I have an array of collections of objects. Each object has a unique ID associated with it. I need some help finding a way to combine all arrays that are related to one another into a single array. Ideally, the final result should have only one instance of every single object.

The objects are referred to as "Modules" and are matched to one another because they share the same coordinates and therefore are touching. The data frequently has this correlation, it's not perfect but it fits the usecase. I already have the data arranged into array of collections, but I need to extract the modules and list only one instance of each module. This should map out the string of modules that are touching corner to corner.

Example of the structure...

```
[
[Module 1, Module 2],

[Module 2, Module 1, Module 3],

[Module 3, Module 2],

[Module 4, Module 5],

[Module 5, Module 4, Module 6, Module 8]
]
```

And so on.... Each module is in an object formatted like so

```
  {
"id": 0,
"coords": [
  [
    { "x": 539, "y": 408 },
    { "x": 594, "y": 414 }
  ],
  [
    { "x": 594, "y": 414 },
    { "x": 597, "y": 381 }
  ],
  [
    { "x": 597, "y": 381 },
    { "x": 543, "y": 375 }
  ],
  [
    { "x": 543, "y": 375 },
    { "x": 539, "y": 408 }
  ]
],
"center": { "x": 568.25, "y": 394.5 }}
```

These modules are "chained" together within arrays that are specific with respect to each module. I.e. Module 1 has it's own chain, Module 2 has it's own chain that is likely to overlap with Module 1's chain... and so on for n modules and v chains.

I'm looking for an idea or way to structure my _.reduce() function such that I can combine all the chains that are related to one another. Ideally, the finished product would be a collection of arrays that contain exactly one instance of every module.

Following the example from earlier.... it would look like

[[1, 2, 3],[4,5,6,8],[7...],...]

I was thinking you could have nested loops to search for related values, but I got a nasty ping pong effect that created a lot of duplicates. Is there a way to "burn as I go" or pop off array entries from memory so that once I establish a chain it doesn't loop back over it?

Attached is the code that sorts the coordinates into objects and categorizes them based on their surroundings

```js
        let testarray = []
        moduleobjects.forEach((firstmoduleobject,bigindex)=>{
            let matchedmodules = [firstmoduleobject]
            firstmoduleobject.coords.forEach(firstline=>{
                moduleobjects.forEach((object,index)=>{
                    if(matchedmodules.includes(object)){return}else{
                            object.coords.forEach(line=>{
                             if((line[1].x===firstline[0].x||line[1].x===firstline[1].x)&&(line[1].y===firstline[0].y||line[1].y===firstline[1].y)){
                                    console.log(line[1].x===firstline[0].x||firstline[1].x)
                                    matchedmodules.forEach(modules=>{
                                        if(modules.id===object.id===false){
                                            if(matchedmodules.includes(object)===false){
                                                matchedmodules.push(object)
                                              }
                                        }
                                        
                                    })

                                if((line[0].x===firstline[0].x||line[0].x===firstline[1].x)&&(line[0].y===firstline[0].y||line[0].y===firstline[1].y)){
                                    matchedmodules.forEach(modules=>{
                                        if(modules.id===object.id===false){
                                            if(matchedmodules.includes(object)===false){
                                                matchedmodules.push(object)
                                              }
                                        }
                                    })
                                }
                            }
                        })
                        
                    }
                })
                console.log(matchedmodules.length)
                let uniqueArr = [...matchedmodules.reduce((map,obj)=>map.set(obj.id, obj), new Map()).values()]
                testarray.push(uniqueArr)
            })

            
        })
        
        
        let finalarray=[]
        let idchecklist = []
        moduleobjects.forEach(object=>{
            idchecklist.push(object.id)
        })

        let finalarr = _.map()
```

Comment: A diagram would really help here. Also does this have anything to do with lodash or node.js? If it's just an algorithm question those tags aren't helping.

Comment: @IanMercer Sure I can sketch something up and add it. What should the diagram show? Also, the function I'm trying to write is a lodash function and I'm using that library. I was wondering if there was a better tool in that library I could use or any other tool within the Node JS network that would help, so I do believe these tags are helpful

Comment: _"an algo that relates coordinates to each other"_ How? How are the coordinates _related_ to each other? Are the modules squares on a grid? Do the coordinates matter or is it just matching modules that happen to have the same values? Explain the geometry behind the question here, or if the geometry doesn't matter maybe remove it and simplify the question?

Comment: @IanMercer Sorry haha that's a good idea. I'll remove all the extraneous stuff and focus the scope of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using of [union-find algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) based on disjoint-sets data structure.

Code is very simple, wiki pseudocode is close to real one.

You have to walk through all element pairs (in longer lists it's enough to get neighbor pairs), after that every element will point onto its parent (set representative element).

Comment: The link you shared was very helpful and this is definitely a step in the right direction. Do you mind sharing a code sample for implementing this in Javascript? I've searched the wiki and I'm having trouble applying the concepts to my specific data structure of array of objects.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know JS enough to write code. Perhaps you can make map, objects should have own id field and parent id field (key in the map). Something like `{id: 2; parentid: 1; "x": 539, "y": 408}`